# Why won't my flash message show? (Cake PHP 2.0)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In AppController:

```
public $helpers=array("Session","Html","Form");
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'MainPages', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'MainPages', 'action' => 'front')
    )
);
```

In MainPagesController:

```
public function front()
{

    $this->Session->setFlash('Your stuff has been saved.');
    debug($this->Session->read('Message'));
    //etc...
```

In default layout (default.ctp)

```
<div id="content">
    <?php echo "Flash:" ?>
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

The correct flash message shows in the debug but not on the view. What am I missing? PS It's not because of space after the ?>.

**Edit: I have discovered that CakePHP is calling the session helper before the session component for some reason. Still trying to figure out how to fix it.**

Comment: Is there   <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?> present in your default.ctp?

Comment: Yes, see third code box.

Comment: The component is never called after the helper. either only the helper, or the component and then the helper! But if you have trouble with displaying the flash messages, try `$this->disableCache()` in the controller. Some browsers are known to cache too harsh and thus preventing the update (as flashmessage) to be properly displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to create flash messages is to create their ctp file in app/view/element dir

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div id="content">
    <?php echo "Flash:" ?>
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?> 
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

You need to define `flash('auth')` in your view to see `authentication session flash messages.`

Comment: It's not an authentication flash message...it's just a normal flash message not defined by anything. The auth flash messages worked in the login fail. Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    My setflash works in this way..
    Keep this in the App controller

    function setFlash($message, $type = 'blue') {
           //what ever the color you need..
            $arr = array('red' => 'red', 'green' => 'green', 'yellow' => 'yellow', 'gray' => 'gray', 'blue' => 'blue');
            $this->Session->setFlash($message, 'default', compact('class'), $arr[$type]);
        }

    and then call it from the controller action where you need to make the flash message as below..

    $this -> setFlash("This is flash message","red");

    now you need to make the flash in the layout(if you are using) or in your ctp file..

    <?php echo $this->Session->flash() ?>
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('red') ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it is because you have an error here:

```
<?php echo "Flash:" ?>
```

You are missing the semi-colon

```
<?php echo "Flash:"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not it though. I took out that statement altogether. I've been working on this for a while typing it in many different ways...can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. It works in other controllers.

Comment: In this case ; is not required.